# Extract a portion of string from a particular string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this

`var str = "WebApi served the request: /api/user/v1 in : 249ms with status : OK";`

I need to extract `/api/user/v1` from str. How do I do it in Javascript?

I have also tried using some regular expressions as shown below. This method works fine, but is there any better way to do it?

```js
var str = "WebApi served the request: /api/user/v1 in : 249ms with status : OK";
var patt1 = /\/.*in/;            //Extract until the word "in"

var result1 = str.match(patt1);

var patt2 = /[^\s]+/;           //Extract the 1st string until it reaches a space

var result2 = result1[0].match(patt2);

console.log(result2);
```

Comment: What is the rule here? How can you identify the string you want to extract?

Comment: please add the fixed parts of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match a slash, followed by non-space characters, until lookahead matches a space followed by `in`:

```js
var str = "WebApi served the request: /api/user/v1 in : 249ms with status : OK";
const match = str.match(/\/\S+(?= in\b)/);
console.log(match[0]);
```

To check that the string starts with `WebApi served the request:`, add that to the start of the pattern and use a capturing group around the `/api` part:

```js
var str = "WebApi served the request: /api/user/v1 in : 249ms with status : OK";
const match = str.match(/^WebApi served the request: (\/\S+) in\b/);
if (match) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

Comment: `(?=\sin)` rather ?

Comment: I prefer to use literal spaces, they're more concise, precise (match *only* plain space characters, not *all* whitespace characters) and work fine. (Though. if it's unknown what sort of whitespace character exists, `\s` would be the right choice)

Comment: To make it more precise, use a `(?= in\b)` lookahead. Or `(?= in :)`.

Comment: This method works. Is there also a way that I can check if the string starts with "WebApi served" and then only extract "/api/user/v1 from that string?

Comment: @SonaliKumari Is the format fixed? Eg, the part you want to match will always be exactly `WebApi served the request:/<something> in`?